# Facing Issue with WordPress Themes?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

When I install the theme in WordPress, in every theme it only shows the blog page, no other page or menu is visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the front page by going to appearance => customization. If other pages have been created, you can create the menu and set its position where you want it to be seen. If your themes provide demo data, you can import and check.